# Evidence that clears someone of charges

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

Is there an adjective for "evidence" with subj meaning?

It would be an antonym for "incriminating".

I've checked "absolving" and "clean(s)ing" but they don't seem to be used in such a combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Exculpatory**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exculpatory) is the word you're looking for: tending to clear someone of alleged fault or guilt. It is specifically used in the context of [exculpatory evidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exculpatory_evidence).